# CSS: Change height of hovered float block without touching another

Tags: html, css

I have a goods list - floating div with `position: relative`. I need to change height of this block (for buttons like 'Add to basket') when I hover it without touching/moving another blocks. For example: [wildberries.ru/catalog/20/women.aspx](http://wildberries.ru/catalog/20/women.aspx)

I've tried to copy styles from that site but have failed. I don't fully understanding how it work =|

I have something like this:

```css
#goods { width: 330px }
.item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.item:hover {
  height: 180px;
}
p { margin: 3px }
```

```html
<div id="goods">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x120" />
    <p>Cool item</p>
    <button>buy</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x120" />
    <p>Cool item</p>
    <button>buy</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x120" />
    <p>Cool item</p>
    <button>buy</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x120" />
    <p>Cool item</p>
    <button>buy</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x120" />
    <p>Cool item</p>
    <button>buy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML / CSS that you have so far to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add an innerWrap `div` to `.item` and use `position: absolute;`

```css
 #goods { width: 330px }
.item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 145px;
  text-align: center;
}
.itemWrap{
  height: 145px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  border: solid 1px #999;
  position: absolute;
}
.item:hover .itemWrap{
  height: 180px;
  z-index: 2; 
  background: #fff;
}
p { margin: 3px }
```

```html
 <div id="goods">
  <div class="item">
   <div class="itemWrap">
<img src="http://placehold.it/80x120" />
<p>Cool item</p>
<button>buy</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="itemWrap">
<img src="http://placehold.it/80x120" />
<p>Cool item</p>
<button>buy</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="itemWrap">
<img src="http://placehold.it/80x120" />
<p>Cool item</p>
<button>buy</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="itemWrap">
<img src="http://placehold.it/80x120" />
<p>Cool item</p>
<button>buy</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="itemWrap">
<img src="http://placehold.it/80x120" />
<p>Cool item</p>
<button>buy</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```